# Calling PowerShell from an ASP page / VBS with parameter

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

We have a deployment web site (html and asp based) where you are given options to choose a database name and you're also required to assign the application name before you click the deploy button. This is currently working on a batch file but we are in a middle of replacing our batch files to powershell commands.

The problem is that the my script doesn't work.

```
        Dim wshell, intReturn
        set wshell = server.createobject("wscript.shell")
        intReturn = wshell.run("%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -verb runAs " & C:\PowerShellDeployment\DeployApp.ps1 & " " & appName & " " & dbName, 2, True)
```

The appName parameter is the name of the app that you have to assign and the dbName is the name of the database that you have to choose from a list of options.

So if someone could help me figure this thing out, I would be grateful.

Comment: The following seems to have progress but it didn't work in the end because it needed to run as administrator.         Dim wshell, intReturn
        set wshell = server.createobject("wscript.shell")
        intReturn = wshell.run("%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -file C:\PowerShellDeployment\DeployApp.ps1 " & " " & appName & " " & dbName, 2, True)

Comment: Does your command work when run from a command line?